# JavaScript engine based on java or jwebpane download link

Tags: java, javascript, rhino, v8

I want to add javascript enable pane in my java webbrowser.
I have heard about Rhinno , v8 etc javaScript engine
but don't know how to use it.
Is there any link for tutorial of their implementation of this as i m new in java.
Or could you please send me link for Downloading Of JWebPane.
Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're writing or modifying a web browser written in Java, that doesn't have a JavaScript interpreter feature yet. If so, then Rhino is probably the easiest thing to use to add it.

There are lots of examples of how to use it on the [Mozilla Rhino examples page](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/examples.html). Rhino is pretty easy to invoke, as [this example](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla/source/js/rhino/examples/RunScript.java) demonstrates:

```
/* -*- Mode: java; tab-width: 8; indent-tabs-mode: nil; c-basic-offset: 4 -*-
 *
 * ***** BEGIN LICENSE BLOCK *****
 * Version: MPL 1.1/GPL 2.0
 *
 * The contents of this file are subject to the Mozilla Public License Version
 * 1.1 (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
 * the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at
 * http://www.mozilla.org/MPL/
 *
 * Software distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" basis,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License
 * for the specific language governing rights and limitations under the
 * License.
 *
 * The Original Code is Rhino code, released
 * May 6, 1998.
 *
 * The Initial Developer of the Original Code is
 * Netscape Communications Corporation.
 * Portions created by the Initial Developer are Copyright (C) 1999
 * the Initial Developer. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Contributor(s):
 *
 * Alternatively, the contents of this file may be used under the terms of
 * the GNU General Public License Version 2 or later (the "GPL"), in which
 * case the provisions of the GPL are applicable instead of those above. If
 * you wish to allow use of your version of this file only under the terms of
 * the GPL and not to allow others to use your version of this file under the
 * MPL, indicate your decision by deleting the provisions above and replacing
 * them with the notice and other provisions required by the GPL. If you do
 * not delete the provisions above, a recipient may use your version of this
 * file under either the MPL or the GPL.
 *
 * ***** END LICENSE BLOCK ***** */

import org.mozilla.javascript.*;

/**
 * RunScript: simplest example of controlling execution of Rhino.
 *
 * Collects its arguments from the command line, executes the
 * script, and prints the result.
 *
 * @author Norris Boyd
 */
public class RunScript {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        // Creates and enters a Context. The Context stores information
        // about the execution environment of a script.
        Context cx = Context.enter();
        try {
            // Initialize the standard objects (Object, Function, etc.)
            // This must be done before scripts can be executed. Returns
            // a scope object that we use in later calls.
            Scriptable scope = cx.initStandardObjects();

            // Collect the arguments into a single string.
            String s = "";
            for (int i=0; i < args.length; i++) {
                s += args[i];
            }

            // Now evaluate the string we've colected.
            Object result = cx.evaluateString(scope, s, "<cmd>", 1, null);

            // Convert the result to a string and print it.
            System.err.println(Context.toString(result));

        } finally {
            // Exit from the context.
            Context.exit();
        }
    }
}
```

So when setting up to execute JavaScript included in a web page, you'd add the various environment objects (`document` and such) to the `scope` object, and then use `evaluateString` to evaluate it.

This is going to be a ***significantly non-trivial task***. If you're still new to Java, I'd recommend starting with something smaller.

Comment: thanQ for your answer n could you please explain me wt is jwebpane?

Comment: @HemenAshodia: I've never used JWebPane. A quick search turns up lots of pages talking about it, though, and [this one](http://blogs.oracle.com/thejavatutorials/entry/html_component) seems to me to describe it in a fair bit of detail.

Answer (score 1):

Usage is very simple

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
   ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
   try {
       engine.eval("print('Hello, world!')");
   } catch (ScriptException ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
   }
 }
```

Best documentation is on Mozilla's website http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/doc.html

Comment: can you please elaborate a little

Comment: We used Rhino only for JavaScript Evaluation on server side. We load scripts from file system and call eval very similar to above example. Unfortunately I never implemented own browser.